# Как узнать до какого элемента прокручена страница

Tags: jquery

Есть вот такая html структура.

```
<div class="main">

<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>

</div>
```

Как проверить виден ли внутри div main div с id например 1 или 2, ну и так далее.
Смысл вот в чем, когда какой то из дивов внутри дива с классом main виден пользователю хочу получить его id

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что в ваших блоках есть содержимое, благодаря которому блоки растягиваются по вертикали, возникает вертикальная полоса прокрутки и вас интересует id того блока, чьё содержимое в текущий момент видит пользователь? А если виден конец одного div и начало другого, что вы надеетесь получить?

Comment: Да, все верно. А если виден конец одного div и начало другого то первый отбросить и брать второй.

Comment: Думаю, https://webkab.ru/dejstvie-pri-poyavlenii-elementa-na-ekrane-jquery/ может навести на мысли.